# django mezzanine file uploads - How uploads directory is created

Tags: django, mezzanine

When I create a gallery(type of page) using django mezzanine, the images are uploaded to:

```
static/media/uploads/galleries/<gallery_files>
```

It is fresh installation of new django/mezzanine project, so dont think that I customized something.

When I created my own model MyModel with an image field like this:

```
i = models.ImageField(upload_to="mymodel_images")
```

When I upload from admin, files are being uploaded to /media/mymodel_images but not to /media/uploads/mymodel_images.

I knw that by changing upload_to to "uploads/mymodel_images" we can make it work but how do I know if its "uploads" or "explodes" ??? I mean, where is that setting or something that decides "uploads" directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')

You can find this in your python installation /Lib/site-packages/filebrowser/settings.py

Normally if you have mezzanine installed, you also have filebrowser.